# Convert [Object text] to plain text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, text, textnode, createtextnode

i have following code:

```
const x = document.createTextNode('Helloooo')
document.body.insertAdjacentText('beforebegin', x)
```

and after execution i see something like **[object Text]**.

My question is how do I see the clear text, thus "Helloooo"?

According the documentation:

- insertAdjacentText (text nodes)
- insertAdjacentElement (nodes)
- insertAdjacentHTML (html string)

What does document.createTextNode return?  I thought a text node, so I use first method, second doesnt works.

Thx for help.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)  returns a `Node`, not a `string`. The second argument to [`insertAdjacentText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText) should be a `string`, not a `Node`:

```
const x ='Helloooo';
document.body.insertAdjacentText('beforebegin', x);
```

If you want x to be a Text Node, you can use `x.wholeText` to get the text of the Node:

```
document.createTextNode('Helloooo');
document.body.insertAdjacentText('beforebegin', x.wholeText);
```

Comment: Okay, is there a way how to convert Text Node to string? Because when i use different function eg, append / appendChild, prepend, thats works!

Comment: you can use `x.wholeText`

Comment: Cool,  i founded too, but little bit later ;-), Okay, thx!